# Automatically follow latest console output in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I have multiple console outputs in my development environment, e.g. one for deployment log, one for server.log. As I recently switched from eclipse, I liked the feature that after calling the deploy task the console showed stuff and a *"build successful"* and afterwards it automatically switched to the server log console showing *"deploying my.war"*.

Now I have to switch to the latest output manually. Is there an option to follow the recent tab of the console?

**Update**: to clarify, my problem is that I don't want to have to click on the server.log-tab and then scroll to the end, after redeploy, to see successful deployment. Plz help.